# Using curl to output http status code, total time, and the request body

Tags: java, json, parsing, curl

I would like to use curl to capture the following parameters in a single POST request:

- http status code
- total time of the operation
- body of the results

Based on the manual (http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), here are the options I tried.

1) The -w parameter captures the http_code and the time_total.

```
curl "http://stackoverflow.com/" -w "\' %{http_code}\',\'%{time_total}\'"
```

But it appears it only returns these two parameters and I am no longer able to capture the body.

2) The -i parameter returns the header and the requested body but I will no longer be able to return the total time.

```
curl -i "http://localhost:8080/"
```

The end goal is place the three results into a JSON object which can then be parsed as needed.

```
{"httpVar: "200", "runtimeVar" : "18.58", "outputVar" : "ID:grinvriar080n23nvn"}
```

Currently, I'm using groovy script (similar to JAVA) so I don't think I could use bash or PHP. I could total time it took the groovy to run the .execute() but that won't be the true time it took to POST to send/return data. I'm even open to using another program besides curl.

I looked for a few days now with no results so any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Found the problem. I had a '-o /dev/null' parameter at the end of my command, which puts the actual body/output into the ether. When I omitted it, it produced the output as well as http_code and time_total.

Answer (score 0):

What you tried should give, what you desired to get.

I mean the following:

```
curl "http://stackoverflow.com/" -w "\' %{http_code}\',\'%{time_total}\'"
```